# Como construir correctamente una matriz en Power BI

Tags: matriz, powerbi

Estoy en la realización de mi primera matriz en Power BI, y quiero representar la cantidad de consumo por plan de cada uno de los clientes de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente en Power BI, he estado construyendo la matriz de la siguiente manera, en donde la columna `NombreCliente` la ubico en su respectivo apartado y los Valores como cada uno de los planes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si lo realizo de esta manera como actualmente lo estoy haciendo en Power BI, me crea la matriz así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden visualizar los planes de cada uno de los clientes pasan a ubicarse debajo de `NombreCliente` como si fuera una columna mas.

Hay alguna manera de ubicar el nombre `Original` y `Actual` como si fuera fila o de representar mi matriz como lo agregue en la imagen al inicio de la pregunta ?

Voy a dejar claro que ya intente mover `Original` y `Actual` al apartado de filas pero no me lo permite ya que son creadas a partir de una medida.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que actualmente tienes la data de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si haces un unpivot a original y actual, podrás hacer lo que requieres, dado que asi ya tomará como categorias a original y actual y no como columnas separadas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta manera ya podrás hacer la tabla.